# How to pass parameters using SSRS to redshift

Tags: sql, reporting-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to setup selecting multiple parameters using SSRS (using SQL) to redshift?

We only have read and execute access to the server therefore, creating a stored procedure or anything else is not an option. If there is (or are) way(s), can someone show me how please?

Thank you.

Comment: You can past multiple parameters to a URL of the report. [MSDN article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52176.ssrs-link-to-a-report-with-parameters.aspx)

Comment: can you elaborate on your scenario, What exactly you need?
You can pass parameters, if you give some more specific info we could add some valuable input to it.

Comment: @AnkUser let me re-phrase my question. In oracle, I can do this:
SELECT DEPARTMENT, DEPT_NO, YEAR, MONTH
FROM DATABASE
WHERE DEPARTMENT= :DEPT
AND YEAR IN (:YEAR)
AND MONTH =:MONTH
I am passing 3 different parameters in this example and my question is how can I write a code in Amazon Redshift (using sql) to do exactly the same thing as in Oracle? Does this make sense?
Thanks.